# Advanced Python book referral needed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am coming from C++ world and just trying to start with Python and gained my initial bearings using "Thinking in C++." It gave me a lot of insights into C++ world and i didn't get lost.

Is there any similar book for python as well???

For basics i used "Learning Python the hard way". I just gave me some insight into how i can code in python but not in-depth as to how its interpreted and if any approach would be faster etc...

Any advice would be helpful...

Comment: Click on the python tag, click on "more ..." to go to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info 
 and read the collected wisdom there. This question is offtopic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [Fluent Python](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491946008) to be a very good advanced book.

Comment: Thanks Dmiti for our help, this seems to be what i was looking for.